# Is there a way to prevent CORS API requests in service worker?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

We have a angular web application that routinely sends a request to another origin. However, we get this error for the api calls.
[image]

Here's our configuration for service worker in angular under `ngsw-config.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/weava-core/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": [
        "https://localhost:8001/**"
      ],
      "cacheQueryOptions": {
        "ignoreSearch": true
      },
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxAge": "30s",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "timeout": "60s"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to let Service worker ignore cors requests?